# Returning a range without hidden rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I this range `$A1:$C` with an associated Slicer:

| Name | Impact | Effort |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | 1 | 4 |
| Project 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Project 3 | 4 | 1 |
| Project 4 | 1 | 4 |

If I set the Slicer to filter out all projects with an effort of 4, the resulting table is:

| Name | Impact | Effort |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Project 3 | 4 | 1 |

Note that Project 1 and Project 4 are not shown, but Google Sheets doesn't delete them, it just hides their rows, so formulas computing the whole `$A1:$C` range will still be able to get Project 1 and 4's values even though their rows are hidden.

For example, using `=INDEX($A2:$A, SMALL(ROW($A2:$A)-ROW($A$1), 1))`, which returns the Name of the first project in the range, will return "Project 1" before and after applying the Slicer's filter. It computes the hidden rows too. The expected result is that it returns "Project 2".

I'm open to solutions that include coding with App Scripts, macros, or any other solution if using only formulas is not enough, although I'd prefer to keep only using formulas.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow thank you, I edited the question with examples. Hopefully it's more clear now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach using [subtotal()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649):

```
=+filter(A2:A,map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,subtotal(3,Σ))))
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: nice use of `MAP()`! What does the `+` at the beginning do? I’ve never seen that before

Comment: use of `+` in this use-case is to restrict the array value to single cell